# React update state only on the second execution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use the useState Hook to update my State in a funcitonal component.
I want to set the state of an object to the state the property of another object after the user click a button. The objects are identical but the order in the Array is different. (The User can sort it in the UI).

When handleSave is executed once it didn't work the order stays the same. Only if the function is executed a second time the state changes.

Here is my code:

```
const [assetItems, setAssetItems] = useState([]);
const [currentMonList, setCurrentMonList] = useState(null);

const handleSave = async () => {
await setCurrentMonList(
  await update(currentMonList, {
    items: {
      $set: assetItems
    }
  })
);
console.log(currentMonList.items);
console.log(assetItems); 
};
```

**the initial state** for both (assetItmes and currentMonList.items) is:

```
0: {id: 1,  …}
1: {id: 2,  …}
```

**after one execution: (user sorted the items and clicked save)** 
*currentMonList.items*

```
0: {id: 1, …}
1: {id: 2, …}
```

*assetItems:*

```
0: {id: 2, …}
1: {id: 1, …}
```

**after the second execution:** (both have the correct values)

```
0: {id: 2, …} 
1: {id: 1, …}
```

I tried:

- an async function for handleSave (still in the provided code)
- a timeout function of 5 seconds before the console log
- changeing $set to $merge inside the update of the state
- calling setCurrentMonList with $set: null and then call again with $set: assetItems

**UPDATE:**

the array sort is via React-DnD. The sort works in the UI. And also in the output of the assetItem state.

```
const moveCard = async (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    const dragCard = assetItems[dragIndex];
    await setAssetItems(
      await update(assetItems, {
        $splice: [[dragIndex, 1], [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]]
      })
    );
  };
```

Comment: add a code sandbox of this?? try consoling just before the return statement. Check there if it's on the second execution.

Comment: How do you sort the array? Can you show use the code?

Comment: i include the sort function in the code

Answer (score 0):

Function for updating state cannot have await inside. You can wrap it in the async function, but it per se cannot be async, since it should update your component's state. I guess that is the reason why only on the second triggering of the function you get what you want. Try it like this:

```
const [assetItems, setAssetItems] = useState([]);
const [currentMonList, setCurrentMonList] = useState(null);

const handleSave = async () => {
await setCurrentMonList({
    items: {
      $set: assetItems
    })
};
console.log(currentMonList.items);
console.log(assetItems); 
};
```

Look what Dan Abramov wrote about it: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326

Comment: don't work. The aync await works fine in the sort function